# L1 converges to zero

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

f $\in$ $L^1$ and some Spaces $A_n$ with $\mu(A_n)\rightarrow0$

My question is, if the following holds and why:

$\int_{A_n} f d\mu \rightarrow 0$

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial when  $f$ is a simple integrable function. In the general case given $\epsilon >0$ there exists a simple  integrable function $g$ such that $\int |f-g| <\epsilon$. Can you finish the proof using the fact that $\int_{A_n} |f-g| \leq \int |f-g|  <\epsilon$?